# Left Join con condicion

Tags: mysql

tengo dos tablas unidad con los siguientes datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que no se muestren los que tengan en accion "cancelados", pero al agregar **AND accion<>'cancelado'** cambia los datos a NULL

```
SELECT equipos.id,empleado,accion 
       FROM equipos 
       LEFT JOIN solicitud_equipos 
            ON equipos.id = solicitud_equipos.id_equipo 
            AND accion<>'cancelado' 
       ORDER BY equipos.id DESC;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté poner la condición con un WHERE pero eso solo hace que no me traiga todos los datos de la primera tabla

```
SELECT equipos.id,empleado,accion 
       FROM equipos 
       LEFT JOIN solicitud_equipos 
            ON equipos.id = solicitud_equipos.id_equipo 
       WHERE accion<>'cancelado' 
       ORDER BY equipos.id DESC;
```

Comment: Puedes agregar la otra tabla para visualizar mejor el problema

Comment: Hola, en la primera imagen están las dos tablas unidas

Comment: si pero no se muestran los campos de la tabla solicitud_equipos para poder observar mejor los datos, seria bueno que las pongas por separado

Comment: Puedes colocar las estructuras de las tablas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La primer consulta, lo que haces es invalidar el `left` del `join`, por lo que en vez del valor `cancelado` obtienes un `NULL`.

La segunda opción es la válida, pero el problema que tienes es la comparación con valores `NULL`, pero lo solucionas indicando un valor "dummy" por defecto en estos casos:

```
SELECT equipos.id,empleado,accion 
       FROM equipos 
       LEFT JOIN solicitud_equipos 
            ON equipos.id = solicitud_equipos.id_equipo 
       WHERE IFNULL(accion, '') <> 'cancelado' 
       ORDER BY equipos.id DESC;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! funciona perfectamente